# how to get all audio files from internal and external storage in android studio

Tags: java, android

How can I access all audio files from my storage internal as well as external in android studio and how can I get recent audio files on top of my recyclerview?

```
       public ArrayList<ModelClass> getData() {

        ModelClass f;
        String targetpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/"  ;
        File targetdir = new File(targetpath);
        files = targetdir.listFiles();
        if (files.length != 0) {
            for (int i = files.length -1 ; i > -1; i--) {
                File file = files[i];
                f = new ModelClass();
                f.setUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
                f.setPath(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                f.setDate((file.lastModified()));
                f.setFilename(file.getName());
                if (!f.getUri().toString().endsWith(".nomedia")) {
                    fileslist.add(f);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Make dummy call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dummyCallAlert();
        }

        return fileslist;
    }
```

[image given below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmODB.png)

Comment: And what is your code doing? Why did you post that code?

Comment: this code only fetch audio files from particular folder . I want to fetch audio files from phone storage.

Comment: From which particular folder?

Comment: in my phone from "Call" folder I get only folder audio not all audios from my phone , how I get?

Comment: I see no Call folder in your code.

Comment: sorry I take wrong screenshot instead of   String targetpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/"  ;          String targetpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "Call"  ;

Comment: If you use it without Call you will get all from external storage

Comment: Yes , you are right , but I want only all audio files.

Comment: I do not understand you.